# Make stress test on endpoint

Tags: java, json, rest, soapui

I'm new in soap Ui.
My goal is to make stress test on endpoint using soapui.

i have to make post request 1000 times and Increment my id value in json

```
{
  "Id": ${valueToIncrement}
}
```

can u provide some info to achieve my goal, pls?

Comment: The first result on google should help ! https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/getting-started.html

Comment: hmm, haven't seen anything related to auto incrementation of field "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick for you:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

def testStep = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("TestStep");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final String json = testStep.getPropertyValue("Request");

    final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    obj.put("Id", i);

    testStep.setPropertyValue("Request", obj.toString());
    testRunner.runTestStepByName(testStep.getName());
}
```